# Why would my data relationship is not created in CoreData?

Tags: swift, core-data

I have two entities in my `CoreDataModel` that should be linked together with a too-many relationship on one wary and to-one on the other way.

These are the `CityEntity` and the `WeatherEntity`.
The `CityEntity` can have multiple `WeatherEntity`, but not the opposite.

I have two main errors that I would like to solve.

- When saving the data, the `NSManagedObjectContext` save as many `CityEntity` as I have `WeatherEntity`, which is wrong as I am expecting only one `CityEntity`.
- When saving `WeatherEntity`, the relationship with the `CityEntity` is not created.

This is the code I am using to save the data.

```
func saveForecast() {

  let cityModel = CityModel(
    name: "Paris",
    weather: [WeatherModel(temp: 12.65), WeatherModel(temp: 12.43)]
  )

  let cityEntity = CityEntity(context: persistentContainer.viewContext)
  cityEntity.name = await cityModel.name

  for weather in await cityModel.weathers {

    let weatherEntity = WeatherEntity(context: persistentContainer.viewContext)
    weatherEntity.temp = weather.temp
    weatherEntity.city = cityEntity
  }

  do { try persistentContainer.viewContext.save() }
  catch { print(error.localizedDescription) }
}
```

These are the result that I get saved in my `CoreDataModel`, which is wrong as I have 3 `CityEntity` instead of one, and no relationships between my `WeatherEntity` and the expected `CityEntity`.

You can see that there is not `CityEntity` saved in place of the `name` when looking at the `WeatherEntity.

[image: CityEntity result]
[image: WeatherEntity result]

This is the way I set the relationship in the `CoreDataModel`:

[image: CityEntity setup]
[image: WeatherEntity setup]

Comment: Forgive me for asking the obvious: Did you clear all application data between different runs of the program? Each call to your function will create a new CityEntity and add it to the database.

Comment: @MartinR Yes, I delete the application from the simulator to clear out saved data.

Comment: Is WeatherEntity a sub-entity of CityEntity? (If yes: why?) In that case each WeatherEntity is also a CityEntity and might appear as such in your database viewer.

Comment: @MartinR If so, how can I know it and how can I solve the issue?

Comment: Check in the Core Data model inspector for WeatherEntity: Is “Parent Entity” set to CityEntity? If yes, reset it to “No Parent Entity” and try again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you (accidentally?) set the parent entity of WeatherEntity to CityEntity. That makes WeatherEntity a “sub-entity” of CityEntity, and the corresponding `WeatherEntity` class a subclass of `CityEntity`.

Then every instance of `WeatherEntity` is also an instance of `CityEntity`, and that explains why there are three instances of `CityEntity` in total after running your code.

Resetting the parent entity to “No Parent Entity” in the Core Data model inspector, re-generating the managed object subclasses, and cleaning all application data should solve the problem.